# jboss as 5.1 logback slf4j log4j

Tags: jboss, log4j, logback

I am using logback in a webapp on jboss 5.1. The webapp is using slf4j API. The output, though, looks like a combination of log4j and logback. The log4j message appears to be the logback output. Hence, tow timestamps, INFO and DEBUG, etc.

2011-02-02 09:34:05,359 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 09:34:05.359 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-2] DEBUG com.clear.wib.servlet.Proxy - wib data available = 1783

How can I get the webapp to only output the logback message? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can.  JBoss hijacks the SLF4J APi and redirects it into its own logging framework, and from then on to Log4j. If you try and re-redirect it to Logback, you're going to get inconsistent results.

Appservers like JBoss provide their own logging facilities. Fighting it is just going to bring you pain.

Comment: Is that still true for newer versions of JBoss ? Jboss AS7, Wildfly 8 ?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by editing jboss-service.xml. You have to remove log4j mbean under 'Log4j Initialization' block in this file and restart the server.

This is not causing any issues to JBoss server logging also.